# Stripe Billing in Laravel 5.1 Class not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, stripe-payments, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to migrate the my app from `Laravel 4.2` to `Laravel 5.1`. I've a stripe implementation here.

I've a `BillingInterface.php` and `StripeBilling.php` in my folder `app\Acme\Billing`.

I've the `BillingServiceProvicer.php` in `app\Providers`

In my `PaymentController`,I'm trying the following code and I'm getting an error:

```
use Acme\Billing;

$card = App::make('App\Acme\Billing\BillingInterface');
try {

   $new_card = $card->addcard([
   'customer_id' => $cards->customer_id,
    'token' => Input::get('stripe_token')
 ]);
```

Error:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 736: Class
>   App\Acme\Billing\BillingInterface does not exist

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How to you map the interface to your concrete implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me:

```
$card = App::make(BillingInterface::class);
```